# N number of inputs on the same line

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    a = input()
```

where N is supposed to be the number of toys and each "a" input is supposed to be each toy's identification as a letter. That would be fine, except the inputs are supposed to be on the same line and since the N number of inputs is unknown until the user's input I can't really use `input().split()` the way I'm used to. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: Show sample input and output that you expect.

Comment: "I can't really use `input().split()` the way I'm used to" Why not?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could just slice off additional inputs.

```
>>> N = int(input('toys: '))
toys: 5
>>> ids = input('ids: ').split()[:N]
ids: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>>> ids
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

With mapping the ids to integers:

```
>>> ids = [int(x) for x in input('ids: ').split()[:N]]
ids: 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10
>>> ids
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**~edit~**

Tiny bit more efficient, because potentially splitting less often:

```
>>> ids = input('ids: ').split(maxsplit=N)[:N]
ids: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>>> ids
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: This. And if you can't have a list as your output you can also use `','.join(ids)` to get a string of "1,2,3,4,5" instead of a list of ['1','2','3','4','5']

Comment: @timgeb that works perfectly, thank you! But I was wondering, is there any way I can make sure the user enters only N inputs? Like something that would lead to an error much like an assertion error for example.

Comment: @Luan not without reading `N` inputs separately by calling `input` `N` times I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to get the number of toys, as you can infer it from the input. Assuming the ids of the toys are whitespace-separated:

```
ids = input().split()
N = len(ids)
```

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question, as it's pretty unclear exactly what you want.